# How to install OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool 2.5 on Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows-10, openxml, openxml-sdk

I downloaded the OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool 2.5 from [Microsoft's Website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

However when I want to install it, I get told I need to install .NET Framework 4 first and the install won't continue without it. I already have .NET Framework 4.6 installed. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

[image]

> You should have .NET Framework 4.0 installed before you setup Open XML SDK 2.5
>
> Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again. The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web. Would you like to do this now?

I already have .net Framework 4 installed.
This is the message if I Click Yes to install it on the downloaded installer for it.
[image]

Version 2.5 of the tool I could find.

In my windows features I don't have an option for .NET 4.0 and only have 3.5 and 4.6 which are already ticked.

[image]

Question:

How do I install the Open XML Productivity Tool?

Comment: You could use a tool like [sysinternals procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see which registry key it's checking (I assume it's looking for a registry key), then just create it to get past the block. Alternatively, you might be able to use [Orca](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx) to inspect the msi to see what it's looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET version messages were a red herring.

It turned out to be a privileges issue.

I right clicked on the msi and selected `Install as administrator` and it installed correctly.

Comment: In Windows-10 (at least my work laptop's configuration) this was not available, but following these instructions here, I was able to add the "_Install as Administrator_" selection: [How to force an MSI Package to Install Using Administator Mode](https://www.howtogeek.com/178826/how-to-force-an-msi-package-to-install-using-administrator-mode/)  However, that didn't work for me, so I posted my answer separately below.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem (.Net Framework ) for install VS2015

go to **control panel - Programs & Feature - Turn Windows Features On or Off** , and check all .Net Framework Features

Comment: The only options I have there are 3.5 and 4.6. Both these are already ticked. See original question for screenshot.

Comment: you should tick completely all checkbox inside options for change .Net Framework features @d234

Answer (score 0):

The "*Install Instructions*" here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425 
Say the following:

> Double-click the *OpenXMLSDKV25.msi* **or** *OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi* program file on your hard disk drive to start the setup program.

It reads like you may do one ***or*** the other.
Like the smaller file may download only what you need, where the larger file contains everything you might not need.  WRONG!

All this time I had been trying the 25MB *OpenXMLSDK**Tool**V25.msi* file and seeing the same error.
I downloaded the 2.5MB *OpenXMLSDKV25.msi* file, ran that with no errors, but still nothing installed.
***Then*** I ran the *OpenXMLSDK**Tool**V25.msi* file and *now* I have the "*Microsoft Office Open XML SDK 2.5*" installed as an app and I verified it works.

Comment: I have tried this and it worked on a laptop with .net 4.5.2 but  on a machine with 4.7.2 it installed but I cannot launch it. Does anyone has a solution to run it on 4.7.2 ?